# "Do your own balance car" can only use torque (Nm) but the tutorial is all voltage. How to convert?

Tags: arduino

I want to achieve a balance car in UNITY, but its [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider-motorTorque.html) (and [here](https://github.com/kurimawxx00/arduino-self-balancing-robot)) is using torque. I am not an electrical engineer.

I searched on the Internet about the production of self-balancing unicycles, and then implemented UNITY in UNITY which has a complete API but can only provide torque as a property but the tutorials are all output voltages.

Can anyone advise me how to relate voltage to torque?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your question is too vague in its current form. Provide more information, where did you stuck and what is the specific problem. You have to explain your problem properly to get help. Further, if you need a collaborator for your project, this is not the right place to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm Chinese, I don't speak English well.

Comment: No issue, same here. You do not need to write complex sentences. Write simple sentences. Spending some effort to formulate your question will help you getting a proper answer and improve your English skill:)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert **Power** into **torque**.

To get from Voltage to Power, you need to know the current and efficiency of the engine.

The Power (that you can convert) will be Voltage  x Current x Power-Factor (which is always under 1).

Example: at 24V, 20A current and 0.9 efficiency factor you have a power of 24x20x0.9 = 243W.

Now sicne you have the power, you use `Power (kW) = Torque (N.m) x Speed (RPM) / 9.5488` to get to your torque.

Comment: VARY Tanks！ What is the source of 9.5488?

Comment: Since the power is given by the product of the torque with the angular frequency, the number 9.5488 is converting a frequency in RPM to an angular frequency in 1/s.

Comment: The 9.5488 likely comes from constants like frequency if you assume 50Hz. But yes, some explanation of 9.5488 would be nice to know.